# Linked list problem with constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hi
I have some issue regarding constructor and destructor. I have list class, which has two inner classes, one private class for the list nodes, and one public iterator class.

Now for the issue, I have written a non-member print function which uses the inner iterator class. When i use this non-member function it will end calling the destructor for the iterator. It doesn't end here though because for some reason it will also call for the list class's destructor. Which causes some problem when I want to print the list content again.

I don't understand why it call the list class destructor as well and wonder if someone kindly can tell me that, and how I should fix it.

I have attached all the code related to the problem

### Main

```
#include <iostream>

#include "sorted_list.h"
#include "iterator.h"
using namespace std;

void list_print(ostream& os, sorted_list list)
{
    sorted_list::iteratorn it(&list);

    while( ! it.iterator_end())
    {
        os <<   "key = " << setw(3) << it.iterator_get_key()   << ", "
        << "value = " << setw(5) << it.iterator_get_value() << endl;
        it.iterator_next();
    }

    os << endl;
}

int main()
{


    sorted_list a;
    a.insert(4,4);
    a.insert(5,5);


    list_print(cout,a);
    list_print(cout,a);
}
```

### sorted_list.cc

```
#include "sorted_list.h"

sorted_list::sorted_list()
{
    cout << "construct sorted_list" << endl;
    this->first = 0;
}
sorted_list::~sorted_list()
{
    cout << "destruct sorted_list" << endl;
    destroy(this->first);

}

void sorted_list::destroy(list_link* item)
{
    cout << "destroy list_link" << endl;
    if(item)
    {
        destroy(item->next);
        delete item;
    }

}

void sorted_list::insert(int key, double value)
{
    list_link *curr;
    list_link *prev = 0;

    curr = first;

    while(curr)
    {
        if(value < curr->value)
            break;

        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(this->first == 0 || prev == 0) //if empty or add first
    {
        //first = create(key, value, this->first);
        first = new list_link(key, value, this->first);
    }
    else if(curr == 0)
    {
        //prev->next = create(key, value, 0);
        prev->next = new list_link(key, value, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        //prev->next = create(key, value, curr);
        prev->next = new list_link(key, value, curr);
    }
}

void sorted_list::remove(my_key_type key)
{
    list_link *curr = first;;
    list_link *prev = 0;

   while(curr)
   {
      if(curr->key == key)
      {
         list_link *remove;

         if(prev == 0)
         {
            first = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = first;
         }
         else
         {
            remove = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            prev->next = curr;
            delete remove;
         }
         continue;
      }
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
   }
}


sorted_list::list_link* sorted_list::clone(list_link* item)
{
   list_link* copyItem= new list_link(item->key,item->value,0);
   if(item->next!= 0)

      copyItem->next=clone(item->next);
   return copyItem;
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE ( 4 well formatted lines in reference solution )

}

void sorted_list::copy(sorted_list* my_this_destination)
{
  if (my_this_destination->first == 0) // copy if empty
  {
      cout << "Copy" << endl;
    //list_destroy(my_this_destination);
    my_this_destination->first = clone(first);
  }
}

double sorted_list::find(int key)
{
    list_link *travel = this->first;
    while(travel)
    {
        cout << travel->key << "==" << key << endl;
        if(travel->key == key)
            return travel->key;

        travel = travel->next;
    }
    return -1;
}

int sorted_list::size()
{
    list_link *travel = this->first;
    int i = 0;
    while( travel )
    {
        travel = travel->next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

### sorted_list.h

```
#ifndef _SORTED_LIST_H_
#define _SORTED_LIST_H_

#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

typedef int     my_key_type;
typedef double  my_value_type;

class sorted_list
{

public:
    sorted_list(); 
    ~sorted_list();

    void insert(int key, double value);
    void remove(my_key_type key);
    void copy(sorted_list* my_this_destination);
    void destroy();
    void init(struct my_list* my_this);
    void print();
    void print2();
    double find(int key);
    int  size();

private:
    class list_link // An inner class inside sorted_list
    {
    public:
        list_link (my_key_type key, my_value_type value, list_link* next = 0);
        ~list_link();
        my_key_type key;
        my_value_type value;
        list_link *next;
    };

    list_link* first;
    list_link* clone(list_link* item);
    void destroy(list_link* item);
    // More declarations

public:
    class iteratorn
    {
    public:
        iteratorn();
        ~iteratorn();
        iteratorn(sorted_list *item);
        list_link* list_begin();
        bool iterator_end();
        void iterator_next();
        int iterator_get_key();
        double iterator_get_value();

    private:
        sorted_list::list_link* current;
    };
};


#endif
```

### iteratorn.cc

```
#include "iterator.h"
#include "sorted_list.h"

 sorted_list::iteratorn::iteratorn()
 {
 }
sorted_list::iteratorn::iteratorn(sorted_list *list)
{
    cout << "construct iteratorn" << endl;
    this->current = list->first;
}

sorted_list::iteratorn::~iteratorn()
{
    cout << "destruct iteratorn" << endl;
}

sorted_list::list_link* sorted_list::iteratorn::list_begin()
{
    return current;
}

void sorted_list::iteratorn::iterator_next()
{
  current = current->next;
}

int sorted_list::iteratorn::iterator_get_key()
{
  return current->key;
}

double sorted_list::iteratorn::iterator_get_value()
{
  return current->value;
}
```

### list_link.cc

```
#include "sorted_list.h"


sorted_list::list_link::list_link(my_key_type key, my_value_type value, list_link* next)
{
    this->key = key;
    this->value = value;
    this->next = next;
}

sorted_list::list_link::~list_link()
{
    cout << "list_link destructor" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Have you tried using a debugger and step through the code to see what exactly happens? Try this, and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Your usage of 'iterator' for this case is inappropiate in C++. Please use the correct terminology to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y no please in you, last time it was to few code. Well if you ain't going to help at least you don't need to comment

Comment: @starcorn: The art is to post the *relevant* code. Not more and not less.

Comment: @Sjoerd: just because it does not conform to the standard library's iterator interface, it does not mean it's not an iterator. The STL did not invent iterators and this seems to me like an implementation of the iterator design pattern, so terminology is appropriate.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: considering the nature of the problem, I don't think the poster would have known which part of the code is relevant or not. Furthermore, since it is *absence* of code in this case that causes a problem, seeing the whole listing is far better than a partial one.

Comment: @starcom: although Space_C0wb0y's comment is poorly expressed, posting a *minimal program that reproduces the problem* will generally 1) help you find you error and learn something; and 2) attract sympathy and help because it is a demonstration that you actually tried something (#1) and have a more interesting question to ask.

Comment: @Andre Although it might be ok when talking to e.g. Java programmers, when talking to C++ programmers using the term 'iterator' for something that is not an STL type of iterator, will be confusing.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I don't see a valid point in what you're saying.`iterator` is a short, descriptive name for the class in question, and the interface complies well with the design pattern. The GoF book explicitely mentions that there are multiple valid interfaces for the same design pattern. Moreover, there are container libraries for C++ other than the STL out there. Would you tell the people behind Qt that they shouldn't have used the term iterator in Qt4? http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq12-qt4-iterators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `void list_print(ostream& os, sorted_list list)` takes a `sorted_list` parameter by copy. A quick and dirty fix (that you should do anyways for performance reasons) is the following:

```
void list_print(ostream& os, const sorted_list& list)
```

Now, your `iteratorn`class takes a *mutable* list, so this won't work as you expect. You will have quite a few methods to change to make this work.

In any case, **your real problem** is the lack of a proper copy-constructor. Right now, when you "copy" a list, both end up sharing the same elements, but your destructor is written as if each list owns it's own nodes. Define a proper copy operation and it will solve your problem.

**More elaborate help on how to solve the problem**: (untested)

Change signature:

```
void list_print(ostream& os, const sorted_list& list);
```

Declare + define copy constructor:

```
sorted_list::sorted_list (const sorted_list& other);
```

Change `iteratorn` interface to support a `const sorted_list`:

```
class sorted_list::iteratorn
{
public:
    iteratorn();
    ~iteratorn();
    iteratorn(const sorted_list& list);
    const list_link* list_begin() const;
    bool iterator_end() const;
    void iterator_next();
    int iterator_get_key() const;
    double iterator_get_value() const;

private:
        // You *should* make this `const` but it is not required.
    sorted_list::list_link* current;
};
```

As you can see, the changes are rather minimal, but need to be applied in various places.

**`const` + non-`const` iterators**:

I applied changes here based on the fact that your `iteratorn` was currently only defining read-only operations on your `sorted_list`. If you want to support write access to allow changing the value stored in list nodes (*never* allow changing the key or you won't have a *sorted* list anymore), you should define *two* iterator classes. See the STL iterator interface for more details.

Comment: is that I need to write a copy constructor for iteratorn class, or for sorted_list?

Comment: The list owns the items, not the iterator. So you need a copy constructor for `sorted_list`!

Comment: the quick fix solved the problem. But since it is a dirty fix I want to solve the problem by using the copy constructor. I 've written a copy constructor in sorted_list. When I call the iterator now it will first use the copy construct right after it will run the destructor before the iterator can do anything with it. I don't know whether it is because I've written a seperat function to do the copying instead for doing it all in the copy constructor.

Comment: The iterator should probably still be using a pointer to `sorted_list` as in the original code (albeit a `const` pointer would be required). If I understand your comment correctly, you've passed the list by copy to the iterator. I'll edit my answer to explain it more clearly, as comment formatting is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You're copying the list by value, so the local copy in `list_print()` destructs at end of scope. Pass it by const-reference instead.

This in turn means you will have to change your `sorted_list` to support working with const lists. In particular you need to have a function that returns a const iterator pointing to the beginning of the list:

```
sorted_list::const_iteratorn begin() const
{
    // returns a const_iteratorn pointing at the beginning of this list
}
```

Notice you need a new kind of iterator: a `const_iteratorn`, which promises it won't change the list.

Then, inside `print_list()` initialize a `const_iteratorn` with the start iterator that `sorted_list` returns, by copy:

```
sorted_list::const_iteratorn s(list.begin());
```

Finally create a second iterator instance that initializes with an end iterator coming from a member function of `sorted_list`, similar to the `begin()` function. This will maintain the const-correctness in `print_list()`.

```
sorted_list::const_iteratorn e(list.end());
while( s != e ) {       // two iterators should be able to compare
    // ...
    s.iterator_next();  // consider ++s
}
```

Also, as André mentioned, the fact you don't have a proper copy-constructor and assignment operator is a severe issue. Make sure that copying a `sorted_list` means copying all its elements, so that the new object owns its own list of elements. Do recall the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).